# Mongoose Model within Model is undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm writing a clean up function for when an object is delete. This is being called as normal.
My problem is; the other model isn't being populated as normal. (It works else where)

Within ModelGame.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var ModelUser = require(process.env.root + '/models/ModelUser');

// Some schema code
// Some schema code
// Some schema code

// Remove ids to users.
gameScheme.post('remove', function(game) {
    game.removeGameIdsOnUsers().then(function(){
        next();
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        next(err);
    })
    ;
});
gameScheme.methods.removeGameIdsOnUsers = function () {
    var self = this;
    return this.users.reduce(function(promise, user) {
        return ModelUser.findOne({id: user}).exec()
            .then(function(foundUser) {
                return foundUser.removeGameId(self)
                    .catch(function(err) {
                        console.log('Error removing game id to user.' + user);
                        console.log(err);
                        Promise.reject(err);
                    }),
            Promise.resolve();
        });
    });
};
```

I get the following

```
TypeError: ModelUser.findOne is not a function
```

When logging the ModelUser it's just `{}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm guessing that this is due to circular includes (`ModelUser` requires `ModelGame` that requires `ModelUser`).

You can get a reference to `ModelUser` at runtime using `mongoose.model()`:

```
gameScheme.methods.removeGameIdsOnUsers = function () {
  const ModelUser = mongoose.model('ModelUser');
  ...
};
```